# Guy meets old friend, tries to steal valuable item from the friends house

Tags: identify-this-movie

**Plot** The protagonist and his girl are in a small town, when the protagonist meets an old friend of his. He somehow convinces his friend to let him take care of his house (housesitting). Along the way the protagonist finds out that his friend has a very valuable item in his house (an old coin or some bonds, I can't remember), so he and his girl decide to steal it.

The main part of the film revolves around them trying to steal the item, but they get into more and more complications (the mess gets bigger and more crazier, a bit like most Coen movies). Along the way our protagonists girl tries to seduce the friend and they do end up gettin it on, but in the end it's all for nothing as they find out the item has basically no value. They're left standing on the street, wondering about all the things they did to get it, and what that has done to their relationship.

- Year: I have no idea about the release, though I saw it on Sky about 4-5 years ago. I would put it somewhere between 1990 and 2000
- Country of Release: Pretty sure it was an American movie.
- Genre: Crime, Dark Comedy.
- Places: One thing I remember about the friends house was that he had a [Japanese garden in the middle of it](https://i.pinimg.com/736x/7c/09/84/7c0984ab56f1284f61eefc7f23592ce5--japanese-garden-design-japanese-house.jpg), which he proudly shows of to the protagonist.

I will answer any questions in the comments or in chat, if necessary.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Best Laid Plans](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0133412/)  1999

A couple tries to steal money from the boyfriend's old friend, and the girlfriend tries to seduce the man.  Also, it ends with the couple outside, near the road. And the man's house does have the garden in the middle.

> "Bryce (Josh Brolin) is a successful man who returns to his tiny hometown for a visit. While there, he runs into his old friend Nick (Alessandro Nivola). The two decide to go out for the night. When they enter a bar, Bryce encounters Kathy (Reese Witherspoon), a blonde temptress whom he eventually takes home for the night. When he awakens, Kathy informs him that she is underage and threatens to tell the police that Bryce has committed statutory rape. Bryce panics and decides to tie her up and hide her away in the basement. He then makes a call to Nick. Unbeknownst to Bryce, Kathy is actually Nick's girlfriend Lissa. The two had schemed to use Bryce's money to pay off a $15,000 debt they owe small-time hood Jimmy (Terrence Howard)."

The only issue is, it wasn't much of a comedy.

Screenshot of the indoor garden:
[image]

Comment: I'm a bit surprised that there still no other upvotes. It's defnitly the right movie.

Comment: Holy hell you found it. NICE work!